# Crear formulario para Lista de Modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un Modelo llamado Pregunta :

```
public class Pregunta
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int peso_id { get; set; }
    public List<int> roles_id { get; set; }
    public int dimension_id { get; set; }
    public int amsa_id { get; set; }
    public int modelo_operativo_id { get; set; }
    public List<Alternativa> alternativas { get; set; }
}
```

Y el modelo Alternativa

```
public class Alternativa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int pregunta_id { get; set; }
    public int maduracion_id { get; set; }
}
```

Por regla de negocio una `Pregunta` puede tener 1 o muchas alternativas (5 es el limite) y necesito crear formulario de alternativas dependiendo de el valor que el usuario selecciona en un elemento `<select>`

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Cantidad de Alternativas</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="cantidad_alternativas">
                <option value="0" selected>Seleccione cantidad</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Para hacer pruebas hice lo siguiente :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.alternativas[i].descripcion, "Descripcion", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.alternativas[i].descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.alternativas[i].descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.alternativas[i].maduracion_id, "Maduracion", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.alternativas[i].maduracion_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Maduraciones, "Seleccione Maduracion", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.alternativas[i].maduracion_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Problema 1

> Como puedo delimitar el final del ciclo for, con el valor que el usuario selecciona en el `<select>`

Comment: No se si se puede mezclar la variable jquery con razor :S

Comment: Me pasa por hablar sin saber. Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056034/579895) de todas maneras,a ver si te ayuda

Comment: quieres que al cambiar el valor del `select` el ciclo `for` cambie?

Comment: Si estimado @JuankGlezz

Comment: No había entendido muy bien la pregunta, pero ahora comprendo lo que deseas hacer. Directamente no se puede mezclar Razor con Javascript ya que primero se hace el render del Razor y luego todo el contenido HTML y Javascript. Se me ocurre hacerlo a través de un HiddenField, estoy viendo si es posible hacerlo de esa forma :)

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr tambien estoy buscando alguna solucion :D

Comment: @sioesi y usando `PartialView` :)

Comment: Desconozco las `PartialView`, averiguare!

Comment: Bro, he investigado y tratado de hacer algo como lo que deseas pero me temo que no es posible, ya que como decía, no se puede mezclar Razor con JavaScript. Otra forma en que puedes hacerlo es agregar cada alternativa de forma manual, [aquí te dejo un ejemplo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/AXVrV) de cómo podría ser.

Comment: Eso quiero hacer exactamente, seria mucho mejor, pero lo que no se es como agregar esos campos para que mi Controlador, reciba la o las preguntas :S

Comment: @sioesi justo en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74717/insertar-m%C3%BAltiples-registros-en-mvc5) lo realizan tal cual, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: en ese ejemplo, lamentablemente utilizan crear mas de un objeto, del mismo modelo. Yo necesito enviar una Pregunta, que ella tiene una Lista de alternativas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He hecho una solución, la verdad es que no es la que mas me acomoda pero cumple la funcion que necesito.

Cree un selector normal con HTML e hice el mismo ciclo `for` que puse en mi pregunta. Con la diferencia que todos los elementos que ahi se creen estaran ocultos.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Cantidad de Alternativas</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="cantidad_alternativas">
                <option value="0" selected>Seleccione cantidad</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="alternativas">

    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="form_alternativas">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.alternativas[i].descripcion, "Descripcion "+i, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.alternativas[i].descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.alternativas[i].descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.alternativas[i].maduracion_id, "Maduracion "+i, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.alternativas[i].maduracion_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Maduraciones, "Seleccione Maduracion", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.alternativas[i].maduracion_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    } 

    </div>
```

En una funcion JQUERY, recorro todos los divs dentro del div `alternativas` y los oculto.

```
$("#alternativas div").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "form_alternativas") {
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        }
    });

$("#cantidad_alternativas").change(function () {
        $("#alternativas div").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "form_alternativas") {
                $(this).addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
        var cantidad = parseInt($("#cantidad_alternativas").val());
        $("#cantidadAlternativa").val(cantidad);
        var contador = 0;
        $("#alternativas div").each(function () {
            if (contador < cantidad)
                if ($(this).attr("class") == "form_alternativas hidden") {
                    $(this).removeClass("hidden");
                    contador++;
                }
        });
    });
```

Dentro de un `Hidden` field guardo el valor de `cantidad_preguntas` inicializado en 0, le cambio el valor cada vez que el usuario cambia el select.

Finalmente en el controlador recorro las alternativas

```
foreach (var item in pregunta.alternativas)
{
    if (item.descripcion != null)
    {
          AlternativaBL aBL = new AlternativaBL();
          item.pregunta_id = result.error;
          aBL.Registrar(item);
     }
}
```

Comment: una pregunta de todo tu problema haces envió de un formulario?, de ser así, estarías enviando siempre 5 alternativas, algunas con sus valores y otras vacías, depende del tipo de dato.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que hago. Con el valor hidden de cantidad de alternativas, se cuantas tengo que tomar. Ademas siempre pregunto en un if si la descripcion o el maduracion_ son distintos de null. Ademas agregue que si el usuario selecciona 5, luego selecciona 4 se limpien los valores ingresados en la pregunta 5 ya quitada.

Answer (score 1):

La idea seria tener la vista dinámica y usar `.load()` para cargar el contenido

primero seria obtener el valor del `select` con javascript o jquery

```
$('#cantidad_alternativas').on('change',function(){
  let cantAlt = $(this).val();
  //cargamos el contenido en el contenedor que sera dinámico (peticion post)
  $('#AlterntivasContenedor').load('@Url.Action("Vista","Controlador")', {id: cantAlt });
});
```

El controlador seria algo así:

```
public ActionResult CuentasEdit(int id){
 TempData["CantAlternativas"] = id;//enviar la cantidad a la vista
 return View();
}
```

La vista seria lo mismo que tienes solo el `for` seria cambiar el 5 por `TempData["CantAlternativas"] as int`.(no estoy seguro si esta conversión sea valida)

Dicho lo anterior para simular el objetivo hice este [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y16iwd) no es tal cual como expongo en esta respuesta pero solo es una simulación, solo hay que cambiar el `JsonResult` por `ActionResult`. Para aclarar lo que [comenta @Flxtr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76660/crear-formulario-para-lista-de-modelo#comment141081_76686), el `return` no regresa un la vista con Razor, si no un HTML renderizado y eso es lo que se carga con el `.load()`.

**otra solución** es generar el código desde jQuery o Javascript:

```
$('#cantidad_alternativas').on('change',function(){
  for(let i = 0; i <= $(this).val(); i++){
    //cargando el dom
  }
});
```

Comment: La conversion no me funciona :/

Comment: Cambia el int por string y luego sería hacer una conversión indirecta (int) TempData["CantAlternativas"] as string

Comment: Mi hermano, ¿pero cómo se estarían generando los controles de forma dinámica dependiendo del valor de la cantidad? Lo que pasa es que el motor Razor primero genera todos los controles del servidor y luego los controles de javascript y html.

Comment: @Flxtr si usa otra vista lo que hace el load() es plasmar el html generado por el servidor

Comment: @JuankGlezz no seria mejor usar `PartialView` ?  para este ejemplo

Comment: @Dev.Joel PartialView o vista daría el mismo resultado

Comment: @Dev.Joel es muy buena idea, enviando como parámetro la cantidad de preguntas y en el `PartialView` un ciclo `for` que renderize los `N` números de alternativas

Comment: @sioesi hice un ejemplo no con un `ActionResult` o `PartialView` ya que no puedo o no se agregar mas vistas en este ide online pero espero se entienda la idea. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y16iwd

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @JuankGlezz, deje una respuesta con una solucion que cree, espero se entienda